# Byebug: Error when using "info locals/variables" for getting variables in current scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, byebug

I am new to rails and trying to debug my code. I am using byebug for it.

The problem I am facing is that I want to know the variables in current scope but when I use any of these commands

```
info locals
info variables
```

it shows the error

```
*** Unknown info command locals
*** Unknown info command varibles
```

I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 3):

The commands you are after are now called
`var local` and `var all`.

Background: Some of the `info` commands have been removed/renamed back in 2014. See this [changelog](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/251e0d3d5bd1228ebc20b151d7b5af4a3783c1c8/CHANGELOG.md#330---2014-08-28) for more information on the change and this [command list](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug#byebugs-commands).

You can type `var` and hit enter to get an overview on the variable commands within byebug.